# Using the nav tag repeat the parent once in the children

Tags: structure, navigation

I'm using the nav tag to build a menu which works great, but i just want to repeat the parent menu item over to any sub nav. So if there is a sub nav, at the top of the sub navs links, i want the parent url repeated once.

My current code is this

```
 <ul>
   {% nav page in blah %}
    <li>
         {% if page.level == 1 %}
            <a href="/{{ section.handle }}#{{ page.slug }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {{ page.getLink() }}
         {% endif %}

         {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
         {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
    {% endnav %}
 </ul>
```

and i'm looking at doing something like (but i would love it to work obviously)

```
 <ul>
   {% nav page in blah %}
    <li>
         {% if page.level == 1 %}
            <a href="/{{ section.handle }}#{{ page.slug }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {{ page.getLink() }}
         {% endif %}

         {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
            <li>{{ page.parent.getLink() }}</li> -- this is dodgy
                {% children %}
            </ul>
         {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
    {% endnav %}
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot, i can just do:

```
<ul>
   {% nav page in blah %}
    <li>
         {% if page.level == 1 %}
            <a href="/{{ section.handle }}#{{ page.slug }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {{ page.getLink() }}
         {% endif %}

         {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
            <li><a href="/{{ page.slug }}">{{ page }}</a></li> -- this is dodgy
                {% children %}
            </ul>
         {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
    {% endnav %}
 </ul>
```